# GridView with ProgressBar setting Invisible

Tags: android, gridview

My app contains a **grid view** which downloads images from net and then shows them on the **imageview** and until then the **progressBars** are Visible. Note all the **imageviews** of grid view have their own **progressbar**.

After the download is complete, the images are shown and then the progress bar becomes Invisible.

**My code:-**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return data.size();
            }

            @Override
            public String getItem(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return data.get(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arg0;
            }

            public class ViewHolder
            {

                ImageView image;
                ProgressWheel pb;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
            {
                View vi = arg1;
                final ViewHolder holder;

                if(arg1==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) itemgridsub.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridsubitems, arg2,false);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.pb=(ProgressWheel)vi.findViewById(R.id.pbsub);

                holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.gridsub_iv);

                    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/comic.ttf");

                    vi.setTag(holder);
                }
                else{
                    holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
                }

                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
               .load(link)
               .fit().centerCrop().into(holder.image,new Callback(){

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops Downloading Failed.\nPlease Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    holder.pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            });


                return vi;
            }

           }
```

**My problem:-**

Activity starts, downloading starts, all the progressbars are shown over the imageview then after the images are downloaded, they are shown in the grid view. But at position 0, i.e. the first grid item the progressbar keeps showing.

All the others items only show images as their progressbar are invisible but the first item is showing the image as well as progressbar.

Why is this happening for only the first progressbar? Whats the error here.

Thanks.